# c code: for loop compiles with gcc but doesn't run

Tags: c, gcc

I'm new to c programming. I'm trying to print numbers 1 to 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<11; i++){
        printf("%s\n", i);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

It compiles in powershell when I type: `gcc .\forloop.c` but when I try to run the program with `./a` I get this error message:

[image: a.exe has stopped working]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Turn on some more compiler warnings!

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm using the -Wall option to compile now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("%s\n", i);
```

That tries to print a string. `i` is an integer. So it will crash when it dereferences `i` as a string.

Try

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Comment: @AlanAu so we agreed to disagree, then let's please delete all these comments.